# Not able to access the data inside of an object

Tags: node.js, nodes, typeorm

I am fetching id column value from database for a particular email. In this case I am passing `email` and want to get primary key i.e id. This operation is successful as I get object which contains Object with the right and expected result. However I am not able to access the object.

I am receiving object like this:

[ UserInfo { id: 21 } ]

And I am not able to access id part of it.

I am using node.js, postgres for database and typeorm library to connect with database.

```
    const id = await userRepo.find({
        select:["id"],
        where: {
            email:email
        }
    });

    console.log(id)
   This prints the above object.
```

The id I am getting is right. But I am not able to retrieve the id part of the object. I tried various ways for e.g.

`id['UserInfo'].id, id.UserInfo`.

Please help me in accessing the object I am receiving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typeorm `.find()` returns an array of objects containing entries corresponding to your filters, in your case, all entries with an `email` field corresponding to the email you specified.

Because the result is an array, you can access it this way:

```
const records = await userRepo.find({
  select: ['id'],
  where: {
    email,
  },
})
console.log(records[0].id)
```

You could also use the `.findOne()` method, which returns a single element and might be a better solution in your case :)

Comment: Thanks @tomrcht. It worked! Did not think of accessing it as an array.

Answer (score 0):

When you are putting a field in the select part `select:["id"],` you are only retrieving this part of the database.
It is like your query was this: `select id from userRepo where email = email`
and you need to put * in the select part to retrieve all the information:

```
const id = await userRepo.find({
        select:["*"],
        where: {
            email:email
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I wanted to fetch the id field associated with the email. Got the solution. The above suggestion worked for me.